# URL hijacked, sort of - how, why and should I be worried?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm seeing a weird url in my google analytics. It's  http://www.lisaredstone.commessage57741318.cenokos.ru/ and it redirects to an ecommece site. My clients site is http://www.lisaredstone.com. What's the story with this - is it something I need to be worried about? How do the .ru's leverage it to their benefit? What actions should I take?

Answer (score 0):

It could just be someone is duplicating your GA account number and using a rewrite redirect. the .ru is a russian extension. I did find this page http://www.cradlecloud.com/how-to-ban-and-block-cenoval-ru-referrer-spam/ that may help you. but if it isn't actively redirecting any of the links on the site (which I tried several) I don't think there is anything to worry about, but someone who knows more about site security may be able to tell you more.

Comment: Thanks Inky. I'm still not comfortable with this, but I don't think there's much I can do.

Comment: Unless you can figure out how they are using your GA account I don't think there is. Like I said someone else may have a better answer for you.